# Seeking Postcode Boundaries for UK, Spain, Canada, Ireland, Brazil

Tags: data, canada, postal-code, europe, brazil

I seek current Postal Code shapefiles for any or all of these countries.

- Spain
- Brazil
- UK
- Ireland
- Canada

Free is obviously better but because I may use them commercially I might need to pay for licensing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, current Postal Code information is usually not freely available, and for Canada and the UK you will have to pay a licencing fee.

There are a multitude of sites that offer this information, such as the two below.

http://www.zipboundary.com/international.html

http://www.geografx.ca/postal-codes-fsaldu-fsa-post-zip-code-point-data.html